# Problem to configuration Java EE in netbeans

Tags: web, configuration, netbeans-platform, java-ee-8

I am trying  to configuration Java EE from  netbeans  12 (I have tried whit the  version  11.3 but had the same  problem) , but  it  doesn't  work,  I have  actived  java web and  EE and then when I go  to the option available plugin  it  doesn't  appear, someone can tell what more I need to do please.

the configuration that I did was the next:

1. I went to:  tools / plugins / installed and active the option of java web and EE
2. I went to tools / plugins / setting and checked that I have the next configuration

   ```
   http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz 
   https://netbeans.apache.org/nb/plugins/12.0/catalog.xml.gz
   ```
3. when I went to tools / plugins / avaibable pluging the opcion of Java EE does't appears
   I have done clic en in option  check for newest but it does not actualize. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk4cU.jpg)